# Send values to a client page

Tags: javascript, php, html, ajax, json

I would like to ask what code should i start to study to perform this kind of task in a webpage...the thing is the server and client is both active..if the server type a values in the input(boxes) and click send it will automatically send it to the client page wich is already opened by a client....is this possible??im just a newbie programmer...help me please.

what code should i study and is there any tutorial about this? can i have a link? please

[image]

Comment: MeteorJS does this logic... you can try it out..

Comment: Are you looking for ajax , im still not getting your question .

Comment: php is server side, you need to refresh the page for changes to take effect, as Kdp said, you need to use AJAX

Comment: You could write some js-code on the client page which executes in intervals and checks in the database for new values and then puts them in the textboxes.

Comment: How long delay is acceptable (time elapsed from the sending of data to the moment the data is put in the textboxes to the client)?

Comment: @Daniel Lisik sup Daniel :D...below a minute, just seconds...i cant find a tutorial just like my concept...help me with this please :D

Comment: @Daniel Lisik i need to send multiple values from server inputs to client inputs.

Comment: @xplody yup, that I got. Wait a few minutes! :)

Comment: @Daniel Lisik yay Okay :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do the work:

**get_data.php**

```
<?php

/* Your db-code
Put it in an array called $data
like:
$data = array('name' => $row['name'], 'age' => $row['age']); */

header('Content-type: application/json');
echo json_encode($data);

?>
```

**JS**

```
function check_for_data() {
    $.post('get_data.php', function(data){
        $("#name").html(data.name);
        $("#age").html(data.age);
        $('#'+data.gender+'').prop('selected', true);
        // etc...
    }, "json");
}

setInterval(check_for_data, 5000);
```

**HTML**

```
<input type="text" id="name">
<input type="text" id="age">
<select>
<option id="male" value="male"></option>
<option id="female" value="female"></option>
</select>
<!-- etc -->
```

## Note

**1.** You've got to have the name the id to the `<option>` tags the same as the possible values from the database for gender.

**2.** Functions like this tend to go heavy on the server. If this will be used by many people on your site, you can make the function check for new data less often (right now it does so every 5000 milliseconds (5 seconds)).

Comment: i put this code to the server? which is the client code here?

Comment: I guess it's two pages we're talking about, right? `server.php` and `client.php`?

Comment: The PHP code should be put in the page where you can send data from, the two last pieces of code should be put on the page where the client sees new data.

Comment: No, I really don't think so.

Comment: ill try your code :D....the script will be put in the client page right? or also in the server?

Comment: @xplody the js script should be in the client page.